# How to use Tire for "MoreLikeThis" query of ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, elasticsearch, tire

I would like execute this [exemple](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/more-like-this/) :

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_mlt?mlt_fields=tag,content&min_doc_freq=1'
```

with [Tire gem](https://github.com/karmi/tire). It's poossible ?

My goal to search document related to another document.

Answer (score 3):

It is not implemented directly in tire. [Karmi](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/273), however, has implemented it as a tire extension in the [tire-contrib](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib) repository.

- Source Code: [more_like_this.rb](https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib/blob/master/lib/tire/queries/more_like_this/more_like_this.rb)
- Add by adding `gem 'tire-contrib'`
- `more_like_this_field(:tag, like_text, options = {min_doc_freq: 1})`

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. I am not sure to build similar request with this extension. Your exemple use "like_text" and not document id to find related document.

Comment: @BastienD If I have understood this correctly then is this method part of the Tire DSL which means you can add it to a search block in tire like any other method (query, size, etc.). The document id is defined in your query and you leave the like text null.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the internet forgot to include a single example of this call (including the source project), so here is one style of it.

```
related_articles = Article.search {
  query {
    more_like_this("#{current_article.title} #{current_article.body}",
      fields: [:title, :description],
      percent_terms_to_match: 0.1,
      min_term_freq: 1,
      min_doc_freq: 1
    )
  }
}
puts related_articles.results.count
puts related_articles.results.first.title if related_articles.present?
```

The gotcha here are the min_term_freq and min_doc_freq params above. They [default to 2 and 5 respectively in ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-mlt-query.html), which makes it easy to get confused while testing this.